# printing content into Browser after reading xml file

Tags: java, xml, xmldom

XML file i have is

```
<xml>
    <ticket>
        <team>A</team>
        <imp>I1</imp>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <team>A</team>
        <imp>I2</imp>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <team>b</team>
        <imp>I2</imp>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <team>A</team>
        <imp>I1</imp>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <team>B</team>
        <imp>I2</imp>
    </ticket>
    <ticket>
        <team>c</team>
        <imp>I1</imp>
```

ticketcount.java

```
package com.asn.model;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import com.asn.model.ticket;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.asn.model.ticket;

public class ticketcount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<ticket>();
        try {

            String Path = "C:\\Users\\";

            File fXmlFile = new File(Path + "\\ticket.xml");

            // File fXmlFile = new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("C:\\Users\// \

            //   \tickets.xml").getFile());
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList ticketNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");


            for (int temp = 0; temp < ticketNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node varNode = ticketNodeList.item(temp);

                if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) varNode;

                    NodeList teamList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team");
                    NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imp");

                    Node teamNode = teamList.item(0);
                    Node impNode = varsionList.item(0);

                    if (teamNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && impNode.getNodeType() ==

                            Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element teamElement = (Element) teamNode;
                        Element impElement = (Element) impNode;
                        ticket ticket = new ticket(teamElement.getTextContent(),

                                impElement.getTextContent());
                        ticketList.add(ticket);
                    }
                }
                String content1 =

                        "<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><TABLE><tr><td>Chain</td><td><b>Priority</b></td<td></td><td>count</td><

                                / tr > ";
                String content = "";
                File file = new File(Path + "\\result1.html");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<ticket, Integer> count = new HashMap<ticket, Integer>();
        for (ticket c : ticketList)
            if (!count.containsKey(c))
                count.put(c, Collections.frequency(ticketList, c));

        List<String> imps = getimps(count);
        List<String> teams = getteams(count);

        StringBuilder heading = new StringBuilder("ticket \t| ");
        for (String s : imps) {
            heading.append(s);
            heading.append("\t| ");
        }

        System.out.println(heading);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");


        for (String m : teams) {
            System.out.println(m + "\t| " + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
            content = content + "<tr><td>" + m + "</td><td>" + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</td></tr>";
        }
        bw.write(content1 + content + "</TABLE></HTML>");
        bw.close();

        Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String url = Path + "result.html";
        //String url = "C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html";//"D:/hi.html";
        String browser = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe ";
        File htmlFile = new File(url);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());

        //   Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + url);
        //    pc.waitFor();

        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html");
    }


    private static List<String> getteams(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
        List<String> teams = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!teams.contains(ent.getKey().getteam()))
                teams.add(ent.getKey().getteam());
        return teams;
    }


    private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps, Map<ticket, Integer>

            count) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


        for (String v : imps) {
            Integer cnt = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
            if (cnt == null) {
                cnt = 0;
            }
            builder.append(cnt + "\t");
        }


        return builder.toString();
    }


    private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
        List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp()))
                imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
        return imps;
    }
}
```

ticket.java

```
package com.asn.model;

public class ticket {

    private String team;
    private String imp;

    public ticket(String team, String imp) {

        super();

        this.team = team;


        this.imp = imp;
    }

    public String getteam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setteam(String team) {

        this.team = team;
    }

    public String getimp() {
        return imp;
    }

    public void setimp(String imp) {
        this.imp = imp;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((team == null) ? 0 : team.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((imp == null) ? 0 : imp.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ticket other = (ticket) obj;
        if (team == null) {
            if (other.team != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!team.equals(other.team))
            return false;
        if (imp == null) {
            if (other.imp != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!imp.equals(other.imp))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("incident [team=");
        builder.append(team);
        builder.append(", imp=");
        builder.append(imp);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: But i am not able to print the content into browser. some where i made mistake.. but not able to find where and what

Comment: You are commented a part of code ` File fXmlFile = new File...` which makes it not compilable.

Comment: it is there String Path = "C:\\Users\\";


    File fXmlFile = new File(Path+"\\ticket.xml");
i didnt comment :(

Comment: yes, but you commented the part of command, and lest part (`\tickets.xml").getFile());`)  becomed uncompilable. If that part also should be commented, comment it too.

Comment: i commented now.. sorry may be it missed while copying it.. sorry

Comment: OK, now it looks better.

Comment: BTW compiler gives error here too: `String content1 = ...` generated HTML(string in general) should be in one line or concatenated as `"..." + "..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this...change Path according to you

```
package com.asn.model;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ticketcount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<ticket> ticketList = new ArrayList<ticket>();
        String content = "";
        String content1 ="<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><TABLE border=3>";
        FileWriter fw =null;
        BufferedWriter bw=null;
        String Path = "src";


        try {



            File fXmlFile = new File(Path + "\\file.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList ticketNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ticket");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < ticketNodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node varNode = ticketNodeList.item(temp);

                if (varNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) varNode;

                    NodeList teamList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team");
                    NodeList varsionList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("imp");

                    Node teamNode = teamList.item(0);
                    Node impNode = varsionList.item(0);

                    if (teamNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
                            && impNode.getNodeType() ==

                            Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Element teamElement = (Element) teamNode;
                        Element impElement = (Element) impNode;
                        ticket ticket = new ticket(
                                teamElement.getTextContent(),

                                impElement.getTextContent());
                        ticketList.add(ticket);
                    }
                }


                File file = new File(Path + "\\result1.html");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                 fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                 bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Map<ticket, Integer> count = new HashMap<ticket, Integer>();
        for (ticket c : ticketList)
            if (!count.containsKey(c))
                count.put(c, Collections.frequency(ticketList, c));

        List<String> imps = getimps(count);

        List<String> teams = getteams(count);


        content=content+"<tr><th>ticket</th> ";
        for (String s : imps) {

            content=content+"<th>"+s+"</th>";
        }

        content=content+"</tr>";

        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        for (String m : teams) {
            System.out.println(m + "\t| " + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count));
            content = content + "<tr><td>" + m + "</td>"
                    + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</tr>";
        }
        bw.write(content1 + content + "</TABLE></HTML>");
        bw.close();

        Runtime rTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String url = Path + "//result1.html";
        // String url = "C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html";//"D:/hi.html";
        String browser = "C:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe ";
        File htmlFile = new File(url);
        System.out.println(url);
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());

        // Process pc = rTime.exec(browser + url);
        // pc.waitFor();

        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\a561922\\Desktop\\TEST.html");
    }

    private static List<String> getteams(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
        List<String> teams = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!teams.contains(ent.getKey().getteam()))
                teams.add(ent.getKey().getteam());
        return teams;
    }

    private static String getNumOfteams(String team, List<String> imps,
            Map<ticket, Integer>

            count) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (String v : imps) {
            Integer cnt = count.get(new ticket(team, v));
            if (cnt == null) {
                cnt = 0;
            }
            builder.append("<td>"+cnt + "</td>");

        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private static List<String> getimps(Map<ticket, Integer> count) {
        List<String> imps = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<ticket, Integer> ent : count.entrySet())
            if (!imps.contains(ent.getKey().getimp()))
                imps.add(ent.getKey().getimp());
        return imps;
    }
}
```

**Now the Output** :-

[image]

I think this the output what you want ... Let me know if u face any issues

Comment: i will try to change this... is there any chance were we can show in tabular format..

Comment: Naren sorry i think i am asking more.. but it is string content how can we can display as table structure..pls help

Comment: Hi have one more small doubt here. In above code i have hard coded as chain , priority count. but actually Headin should  StringBuilder heading = new StringBuilder("ticket \t| ");
        for (String s : imps) {
            heading.append(s);
            heading.append("\t| ");
How we can add this in HTML heading

Comment: yes Heading are coming but values seems completely coming under 1 column

Comment: @ naren thanks a lot.. you are gem..can you suggest me or help me how can i convert this in to an applet.

Comment: ihave one java program where it save's the file xml file. This java program will read the xml and display the count.if we make as applet jar file. so that it can be used by any one but have that jar file right? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Thanks Naren.. i have accepted this answer. can you help me on the applet thing.

Comment: I dont know about applets clearly, i dint worked on applets concept ..otherwise i might have helped u

Comment: can we run this program automatically every hour and display out put in java

Comment: @ naren can we increase size of the count  content = content + "<tr><td><font size = 10 >" + m + "</font></td>"
                    + getNumOfteams(m, imps, count) + "</tr>";   for the count not able to increase the size